# A company I've already applied at will be at an upcoming job fair. (How) can I use that opportunity to increase my chances of being interviewed?

Tags: job-search

I have a career fair coming up in the next few months or so and I'm very interested in one of the companies that will be attending. From what I know this company normally hires through it's online portal and **I have already applied** through it.

What should my next steps be at the career fair with the goal of getting an interview? keeping in mind that the recruiter there has likely not personally reviewed my resume and would likely direct me to apply online if I'm interested in a position. **Can I do anything to increase the chance of my application being selected for an interview?**

Comment: [Reopen is being discussed on meta.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/reopen-how-can-i-increase-the-chances-of-scoring-an-interview-when-meeting-a-co)

Comment: Usually the recruiters are there to do more then just redirect you to the website. Often they will talk to you and write up a quick interview impression sheet that goes in to their HR database to be attached to any application you make. So, go talk with them, indicate you've applied already, ask good questions, and answer theirs to the best of your ability.

Comment: You're probably increasing your chances of an interview simply by showing up, interacting, and telling them you've applied. If HR has to wade through 100 applications, being able to put a face to a name is a good thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know for sure if the recruiter *will* redirect you to apply online is when you attend the job fair and inquire about opportunities in that company. I can see two scenarios:

`1.` *The recruiter redirects you to the online application:* If this is the case, then you are already one step ahead of other possible recruits. This gives your application better odds to be reviewed before others and possibly get an interview.

`2.` *The recruiter does not redirect you, and asks for your contact information right there:* You should then proceed to give them your information, as in this case having applied online and physically doubles your chances of being reviewed/interviewed before others.

---

Remember, you should still bring your contact info with you either way: In `2.` you will definitely need to hand it down, and in `1.` the recruiter may be willing to receive it anyways, thus further increasing your chances of being interviewed.

Either way, do mention that you have applied online, *after* inquiring on their jobs and company: In case `1.` you could then ask them "what else can I do now I already have applied?", so there is a chance that you could speed things up now that part is done. In case it is `2.` then they will see you are indeed interested in their company, which also favors you as a possible recruit.

Note: As @Weedoze suggests, it would be a wise idea to ask for the recruiter's business card.